# Q：Print all subsequences of a string, including empty strings, implemented recursively, and report an error：expresstion:string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, string

Please help me debug this code. It gives me an error "String subscript out of range".
Print all subsequences of a string, including empty strings, implement recursively, and report an error.
I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#include<vector>

class PrintSubstr
{
public:
    void printsubstr(string str)
    {
        string s;
        
        process(0, str,s);
    
    }
    void process(int i,string str,string s)
    {
        if (i==str.size())
        {
            print(s);
        }
        string sc1;
        sc1 = s;
        sc1 += str[i];
        process(i + 1, str,sc1);
        string sc2;
        sc2 = s;
        process(i + 1, str, sc2);
    }
    void print(string s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << s[i]<<"";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    PrintSubstr p;
    string str("abc");
    p.printsubstr(str);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The compiler warning `warning C4717: 'PrintSubstr::process': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow` is a good place to start along with running the code in the debugger to see where and why it crashes. `sc1 += str[i];` is where I see a crash when `i == 4` which is out of range for the string `"abc"`.

Comment: I know what went wrong, I forgot to add the if else statement in the boundary conditions. i really appreciate it!!!

Comment: `Print all subsequences of a string, including empty strings` There are infinitely many empty substrings in every string. So, you could write a program that prints empty string in an infinite loop, and declare (not in programming sense) that the non-empty substrings will be printed after all of the empty ones have been printed. The fact that you wouldn't have written the part of the program that actually does it is simply an optimisation.